# PHP: Arrays as Attributes

Tags: php, arrays, object, attributes

If I have an object with an array as an attribute, what is the easiest way to access it?

```
$obj->odp = array("ftw", "pwn", array("cool" => 1337));

//access "ftw"
$obj->odp->0

//access 1337
$obj->odp->2->cool
```

This doesn't seem to work. Is there something I'm doing wrong, or do I have to first assign it to a variable?

```
$arr = $obj->odp;

//access "ftw"
$arr[0]

//access 1337
$arr[2]["cool"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays can only be accessed with the array syntax (`$array['key']`) and objects only with the object syntax (`$object->property`).

Use the object syntax only for objects and the array syntax only for arrays:

```
$obj->odp[0]
$obj->odp[2]['cool']
```

Comment: are you sure you can access objects with the array syntax? I am trying to do that, and getting this error:

Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\CUMF3\sites\all\modules\results\results.module on line 80

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$obj->odp[0]['cool']
```

Answer (score 0):

`$obj->odp` is an array, so `$obj->odp[0]` reads "ftw". There's no such thing like `$obj->odp->0`.